# how can I create the solution file for already existing visual studio 2003 web project

Tags: asp.net

I have one visual studio 2003 web project, I got this project form my friend, and how can I run this application in visual studio 2003.Becuse now I don't have a solution file for this application. In my system I don't have administrative access.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new solution (empty) and import all the existing files you got.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be administrator. Just create an empty solution file (1 directory level above the project is convenient).

Then use "Add existing Items" and multi-select all files you want to add. You can do this in several steps. Add references that are missing.

Comment: In addition, if you have an existing project file (vbproj), you can add an existing project to your blank solution.